# Running Activerecord asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, asynchronous

I have some worker which take data from a queue ( rabbitmq ) and inside the worker I want to create records using activerecord asynchronously, my current implementation is something like :

```
require "rubygems"
require "amqp"
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

AMQP.start(:host => $AMQP_URL) do |connection|
  @queue ||= AMQP::Channel.new(connection).queue("results")

  @queue.subscribe do |body|              
    EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://someurl').post :body => {:message =>  body }    
    Record.create!(:name => body)
  end
end
```

I want to run **Record** in asynchronous way to bost the performance , any recommendations here ?

Comment: can u tell me how to use it in the regards of this code ? i've been trying to use it all day long but didn't manage to do so

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at delayed_job:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: it is the worker and the queuing system that i'm looking for it is the  mechanism to insert queries in parallel way , i'm using rabbitmq already and i'm not using rails at all here , just ruby processes and activerecords